# Changing keras model input name

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

When i'm creating model ensemble consisting of 6 models in keras i do the following:

```
out = keras.layers.Average(name="output")(outputs) #6 models
model = Model(input, out, name='ensemble')
```

i would like to set the input to be

```
input = Input(SHAPE, name='my_input')
```

but then i get the error message because from what i understand when making an avarage model it's input was automatically set to 'input_6', so i get an error: **Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_6:0", shape=(?, 256, 256, 1), dtype=float32)**. Is there a way to change model input name?

Comment: Please provide more code. What is this input layer you are referring to? How is it connected to other 6 models you mentioned?

Comment: I've got six models of input Input((256, 256, 1)), and then for the list of models (named "models") i do outputs = [model(model_input) for model in models]. I was wondering if there is a way to specify input and output name so that if model changes, they will stay the same.. the purpose of that is reading into anouther application that i don't want to change everytime model changes.